# Problems with google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

Edit:
I had an object called "Function" in one of my scripts that messed it up.

```
var Function = {
    ...
}
```

Solved!

---

I'm having trouble running google charts on my page

Here's a jsfiddle using the exact same code as I do on my page: http://jsfiddle.net/4vBPx/

Edit: The jsfiddle works fine, but I can't get it to work.

This is the error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js:23
V format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js:23
Ep format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js:179
Dp format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js:179
drawChart cpanel.js:166
google.load.callback
```

The code on line 166 in cpanel.js is:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
```

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me.

Comment: It works on jsfiddle, but not on my page.

Comment: Then it has to be something with your server. What does your full HTML source code look like?

Comment: It's a gigantic project, I can't dump all that code.
Everything else works, could some of my code interfere with the google chart code?

Comment: I would assume. Since it works in JSFiddle without any other included scripts, it most likely has to do with a script interfering .

Comment: I fixed it, first post edited.